# access static functions with this

Tags: javascript, class

If I have a class:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  getArea() {
    return Rectangle.area(this.height, this.width);
  }

  static area(height, width) {
    return height * width;
  }
}
```

Then I can make an instance of that class and call my `getArea` function on the instance:

```
var x = new Rectangle(5,6);
console.log(x.getArea());
```

Now, say for some reason in my `getArea` function, instead of calling `Rectangle.area` directly, I wanted to find the class dynamically and call the static method on whatever dynamically the class instance is:

```
  getArea() {
    return this.class.area(this.height, this.width);
  }
```

In PHP, I can do that by something like `static::area()` or `self::area()`. How can I do something similar to `static` and `self` in Javascript to dynamically access static methods from the class that `this` belongs to?

Comment: did you tried it with just `return this.area(this.height, this.width);`

Comment: @Ifaruki That ain't working…

Comment: you can create a property in constructor which refer to its __proto__ chain to access it.
All static property or method stored in constructor property:

create a property in constructor "    this.self =  this.__proto__.constructor" 
Now self variable has access of all the static method and property.

  getArea() {
    return this.self.area(this.height,this.width)
  }

Comment: @deepak Why all that bending over backwards when `this.constructor.area(..)` will do?!

Comment: @deceze - surely it will work , I just want to make clear how object store static data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to `x.constructor.area()`. When an instance is created, its `constructor` property will be made to refer to the constructor function. That's where static methods are found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqcxLok7/) to test how `this.constructor` works when you extend a class.